# Returning an integer in dart

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter

I want to do something like this:

```
int _radioValueGender == _radioValueGender

void setRadioValueGender(DocumentSnapshot document) {
    if (document['gender']=='female') {
        return _radioValueGender == 0;
    }
    else {
        return _radioValueGender == 1;
    }
}
```

Where I set the value of an integer _radioValueGender depending on the result of an if/else statement. I would be really appreciative of any help. I hope that this is easy, it just seems to be a question of knowing the right methods. I apologize for any inconvenience and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `==` is the equality *comparison* operator.  It does not do variable *assignment*.
2. `setRadioValueGender` is declared to have a `void` return type.  It is incorrect to return values from it.

What you want is:

```
void setRadioValueGender(DocumentSnapshot document) {
  if (document['gender']=='female') {
    _radioValueGender = 0;
  } else {
    _radioValueGender = 1;
  }
}
```

or more concisely:

```
void setRadioValueGender(DocumentSnapshot document) {
  _radioValueGender = (document['gender'] == 'female') ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! Also a great explanation on == vs =

Answer (score 1):

Simply modify your initial `int _radioValueGender == _radioValueGender` declaration and make it `int _radioValueGender;`.  That way it forces the value to be any `int` object.

Then instead of `result` use `setState(() {_radioValueGender =
 0 });` in order to modify your variable anytime 'setRadioValueGener' has been pressed.

Answer (score 1):

== is a comparison, when you type that you are asking if the two values on the left and the right are equal. = is an assignment, when you type it you are assigning the value on the left to the right. so just change it to this:

```
  void setRadioValueGender(DocumentSnapshot document) {
if (document['gender']=='female') {
  return _radioValueGender = 0;
}
else {
  return _radioValueGender = 1;
}
}
```